# i want to make view Like in i carousel View

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics, icarousel

i wanna make an array of UIImage in like this view http://i42.tinypic.com/25z1na0.png

which i take them from icarousel Code on Github can anybody help me to make this view

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem are you having? Or are you just expecting someone to write the code for you?

Comment: Have you tried the example from [Cocoa controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel)?

Comment: @NickBull can you give me a useful answer

Comment: @khaled That was a useful answer. You should learn from that and realise that you will be much more likely to get an answer if you actually show that you have put some effort in yourself. We aren't here to do your work for you. You put in your question that you are using the icarousel code on github (which someone pointed you to in your other question) but yet you accept an answer that points you to the SAME github project, but for the examples. So you haven't even bothered to look at the previous link you were given in a previous answer.

Comment: @NickBull i try to ask my question in many ways 
this is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063290/rotating-two-uiimageview-in-x-direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/tree/master/Examples).

Comment: @khaled: Look, we know you and Mustafa here are either socks or co-workers.  Please don't bother trying to artificially raise each other's reputation like this.  You're only going to get suspended, blocked or banned.